# Twilio - retry if message was undelievered due to any reason

Tags: sms, twilio

Does Twilio retry sending sms/message if message was undelivered due to any reason. for eg.

> Unreachable destination handset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twill automatically retries deliveries for you, and has a lot of built in redundancy, so trying to send a message again will just cost you more in credits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: This hasn't been my experience. I got an error 30003 "Unreachable destination handset." and Twilio tried twice (just a second or so apart), then stopped. Their troubleshooting page suggests "just try again".